# Simplifying an Infinite Series (Limiting Distribution)

Tags: sequences-and-series, stochastic-processes

I am solving for the limiting distribution of a Markov Chain, and I have the following system of equations:

$$\Pi_{i}= \alpha_i\Pi_0 + \Pi_{i+1}$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \Pi_i =1$$

Any advice for how to simplify this?

Comment: Some conditions are needed on the $\alpha_i$ for a stationary distribution to exist...

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to mention that the infinite sum of the $$\alpha_i$$ is also 1

Comment: Use the recurrence to find a closed-form for $\Pi_i$ in terms of $\Pi_0$ and $\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_{i-1}$, then use the condition that the $\Pi_i$ sum to $1$ to find $\Pi_0$.